# Insert image into BLOB field of MYSQL table

Tags: mysql, image, blob, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to insert image from file into MySQL table.
The field is longblob. It works fine if i do it manually in MySQL Workbench using "Load Value from File". However, I would like to do it via query:

```
insert into table1(field1, field2, image1) 
values('value1','value2',load_file('path\to\file\file.png'))
```

When I ran the query, field1 and field2 are updated as intended, but nothing happens to the image1 field (remains Null).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the data into byte array and then fill it in the mySQL table.

VB.Net example :

```
Dim data As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)
```

Comment: load_file does that. I just need to figure out why field is not updated.

Comment: what happens when you execute the query?
Does it throw any exception or it executes successfully
Also please share load_files code.

Comment: no exeptions. updates text fields, leaves blob as null